# Bit operation: Similar operation results in different results

Tags: c++, c, operators, bit-manipulation

This following piece of code does not evaluate to what I think it should have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {

    uint32_t var = 0x55555555;
    uint32_t res1 = (var & (0x3 << (15*2)) >> (15*2));
    uint32_t res2 = (var & (0x3 << (14*2)) >> (14*2));
    printf("result1 = 0x%08x\n", res1);
    printf("result2 = 0x%08x\n", res2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

result1 = 0x55555555

result2 = 0x00000001

Can anyone explain why would result1 and result2 differ when the exact same operation is being performed? What am I doing incorrectly while performing the bit-shifting and bit-wise and?

Comment: `0x3 << (15*2)` == `3 << 30` == overflow for 32 bits (undefined behaviour)

Comment: Decompose `var & (0x3 << (15*2)) >> (15*2)` into smaller operations, look at the intermediate values and you'll find out.

Comment: if you want to get the top 2 bits back, use `0x3U << (15*2)` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this expression

```
(var & (0x3 << (15*2)) >> (15*2))
```

integer constant `0x3` has type `int` . After this operation

```
(0x3 << (15*2))
```

the sign bit of the result integer value is set.

After this operation

```
(0x3 << (15*2)) >> (15*2)
```

the implementation (it is implementation-defined) propogates the sign bit to the right. So all bits of the result expression are set.

And you will get

```
var & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

will yield `var`.

In the second expression the sign bit is not set and after operations

```
(0x3 << (14*2)) >> (14*2)
```

you will get `0x3`

```
0x55555555 & 0x3
```

will yield 1.

Comment: This makes perfect sense now! Although, all previous answers did tell the same thing essentially. I accidentally set the sign bit of a signed integer constant. Phew!

Comment: @SudeepMohanty I am  glad.:)

Comment: Just a side-note: To avoid problems creeping in from signed literals where you would expect unsigned math, use the 'U' suffix. There is even a related MISRA rule.

Answer (score 4):

15 *2 = 30. 0x3 = 2 bits -> sets highest bit in uint32. Since 0x3 is signed, this is a negative number. Shifting it down 30 bits gives 0xFFFFFFFFF. Of course, the same doesn't happen if you shift 0x3 up 28 bits and then down again.

If you actually want to pick out the two bits at bits 31&30 and 29&28 respectively, I would do:

```
uint32_t res1 = (var >> (15*2)) & 0x3;
uint32_t res2 = (var >> (14*2)) & 0x3;
```

This also saves one shift, aside from being "more correct".

Comment: Thank you for this alternate method which I also agree to. But unfortunately I am not in the position to change the construct of the code. :/

Answer (score 3):

The type of 0x3 is a signed int. The C standard says:

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. [...] If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

0x3 * 2^30 is not representable in an int.

Change the constant to 0x3U and you'll get correct behavior.

Comment: Thank you much! The 0x3U did solve it out. I now understand what was going wrong:)